# How to you create a method that is called with the main window come active in a WPF app?

Tags: wpf

How to you create a method that is called with the main window come active in a WPF app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override [Window.OnActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onactivated.aspx) in your main window (or subscribe to the main window's [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated.aspx) event).